# Ubuntu-20.04-kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init! exit ==0x00000100

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel

After installing the updates, got the system struck at logo option and while trying advanced options I got the below error message after selecting the recovery option.

[image: Error showing after recovery option]

I have tried to update grub and Boot-Repair option, and tried booting from a live USB, but it was not successful. My system is a dual boot with Windows. Even after deleting the Windows partition, the problem still persists.

Comment: It would be useful to get the lines just before the Call Trace stack. Can you get to them and show a photo?